# Generic term for 'row' and 'column'

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

Is there a single, more generic term that can be used to describe both a *row* and a *column*?

In English, we can refer to a *line* as being horizontal or vertical, but unless we say ‘a line of something’, that implies a one-dimensional line—it doesn't communicate a row or a column of *things*. So what could we say instead…? A horizontal or vertical _______?

Comment: Rows and columns are 'linear arrays'.

Comment: In chess rows are _ranks_, and columns are _files_; in math the rows and columns of a matrix are _vectors_. In spreadsheets terminology, rows and columns are _arrays_, although what Kris wrote would be more precise.

Comment: In spreadsheets specifically, a subset of the sheet is often called a *range*.  Rows and columns are almost always just called "rows and columns", though.  You should perhaps give an example of a context where you want to use the word?

Comment: @TaliaFord On that note, is there a general term for 'ranks' and 'files'? :-)

Comment: @DuncanMatheson Haha, true that :-)

Comment: @starwed [old question but] the example context that led me here is for within an application, where you choose one row or one column, then do things with the cells in your chosen [row/column]. "**Range**" looks best for my needs (obviously can't speak for the original asker).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming (including programming variables) is off topic. Please visit the [help] for more details.

Comment: @CJDennis, if the question had been asked in Stack Overflow, it would have been closed for being 'opinion based'. But it's a good question, so where does it belong? I would say right here, because it's fundamentally a question about *word choice and usage*, even if the background context (as we learn in Duncan's 'edit') happened to be the naming of a programming variable. I'm going to remove the edit and suggest that the question be reopened.

Comment: The question was closed for failing to meet EL&U's standards for "choosing an ideal word or phrase." But the question was asked at least a couple of years before those standards were adopted, which means that, in effect, it is being subjected to prosecution under an ex post facto law.

Comment: Coming back to this years later, reading discussion. Yes, the 'reason' I came to ask the question was programming, but I asked because of linguistic curiosity. I was curious as to whether from a _linguistic_ perspective, there was a hypernym for row/column - and rank/file, as it happens. I see a linked question asking the same, more cleanly. The overall answer turns out to be, "no, a clean hypernym does not really exist", and that, to me, is interesting and worthwhile. I think removing my edit about background context and leaving the pure language question was a good resolution.

Comment: @DuncanMatheson I just wrote my own version of this question also from a programming context, which showed it had already been asked. In general the AI chatbots can be extremely good at bikeshedding. I didn't ask it to bikeshed or ask for it to invent a variable name or type name and only tried once on one chatbot, but it didn't think of anything. However in the context of programming we can make up terms and I just decided "unit slice" would work perfectly.

Answer (score 11):

I think the word he is look for is "vector"; i.e. a line of indeterminate length in a specific direction.

Comment: Not coincidentally, *vector* can also mean "a matrix with one row or column".

Comment: I agree with the word vector, but your explanation should be improved, including references to common usage or authoritative definition. " a line of indeterminate length in a specific direction" doesn't really respond clearly to the question.

Answer (score 8):

How about *[axis](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/axis)*?

> 1. (Mathematics) one of two or three reference lines used in coordinate geometry to locate a point in a plane or in space.

(Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged)

**Update:**

You say you're looking for a name for a code variable. Seeing as people here struggle so much to find such a word, I'm guessing whatever you settle on will confuse whoever reads your code just as much. I'd just skip trying to be pithy and go for `rowOrColumn`. Clarity over brevity.

Comment: This is valid in some uses - *row* or *column* can mean the index of the row or column as a means of addressing (along the lines of r and c axes), or it can mean the contents of an entire row or column, for which axis doesn't match.

Comment: I disagree with *axis* because a row doesn't need to lie along the x axis and a column doesn't need to lie on the y axis, though each will be parallel to one or the other axis. But I voted up your conclusion that `rowOrColumn` would work in code when English lacks a term perfectly fitting the definition.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you all for your suggestions.
I need this term for a logical function name in an assignment for students who aren't programmers, so a lot of the words put forward here would not mean much to them.

I asked a colleague about it and he suggested **'line'**.
I'll use this as it makes logical sense for the match 3 game example project they will be completing, and I thought I'd return and share.

Answer (score 5):

**Vector**

What you describe are referred to as row vectors and column vectors. (Collectively, they are vectors.)

For example, in linear algebra, a row in a matrix represents the coefficients of one linear equation from a system of linear equations. Taken alone, that row is considered a vector (a row vector), and can just as easily be used to calculate the solution for that single linear equation. The "vector dot product" is used with a row vector and a column vector. [Here is a link to a simple explanation](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/systems-linear-equations-matrices.html) for those less familiar with this concept. This picture (from the article) illustrates the idea:

[image]

While the picture also illustrates a column matrix, it's a degenerative case where there is only one column [x y z] in the matrix. But the concept can be extended over multiple columns, where the result of multiplying a row by a column follows the same vector dot product process.

Less common in the context, **Tuple** is an ordered list of elements. As [this article in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) states, a tuple can be used to represent other objects in mathematics (besides a simple list of elements), with vectors being the first example. You might consider **"tuple"** to be a **hypernym of "vector"**.

When it comes to tables like spreadsheets, I would consider some cases of a delineated part of a column or of a row to be a **list**. (I say "delineated part" because the spreadsheet array is so expansive that we often might put multiple independent tables and arbitrary objects in an array.)

Answer (score 3):

Other word for a row and a column can be "tuple".

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking. A tuple would be representing a row and a column as "row, column", an ordered collection of values. He's looking for a generic term, such as "spreadsheet axis", that describes either of them.

Comment: Why would a tuple need to be representing a row and a column as (row, column)? Just because 2-tuples frequently represent (row, column) doesn't mean all tuples must. 

I can't see a reason why a tuple can't represent all the data in a row or all the data in a column if so desired.

Comment: In programming a *tuple* is generally a 1-dimensional heterogeneous collection and can be seen as a generalization of an *array* or *vector* which are terms for homogeneous collections. Arrays may be either 1-dimensional or multidimensional depending on the language etc, arrays are specifically 1-dimensional. (Just explaining for any wanderers who don't already know these technical details.)

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is **series**.  This is the term used in *pandas* for either a row or a column taken from a rectangular  *DataFrame*.  [*Pandas*](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is a widely used open-source data analysis package written in Python.

The key idea is that a series is *iterable*, and that the elements have *indices*, which can be column headers (to index a row) or row names (to index a column).  However, it doesn't matter whether the series itself comes from a row or a column.

As you might expect, it is possible in *pandas* to assemble a *DataFrame* from a list of series, which can become either the rows or the columns, depending on the construction technique.

A *series* can be converted to a *numpy array* or to a Python *list*, i.e. these are common terms for a one-dimensional data structure.  However, neither of these have arbitrary labels like a *series*, which is possibly why the designers of *pandas* chose the term, and why it might be a plausible choice for the application you hint at in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I propose "**band**".

I am suggesting this as a new usage, as we do not seem to otherwise have a common word for this kind of thing.

I was coming at this question from the perspective of separating the row/column from the dividers separating them. The dividers, being narrow, are properly referred to as lines:

> 2: a straight or curved geometric element that is generated by a moving
> point and that has extension only along the path of the point

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/line

In typical usage, a band is generally something thin and long, but generally indicates non-trivial thickness:

> 3: a strip serving to join or hold things together (belt, book band)
>
> 4: a thin flat encircling strip (strip of cloth, ring of elastic)
>
> 5a: strip (as of living tissue or rock) or a stripe (as on an animal) differentiable (as by color, texture, or structure) from the adjacent material or area
>
> 5b: a more or less well-defined range of wavelengths, frequencies, or energies
>
> 5c:  range 7a

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/band

I particularly like the wavelength example; in science, we can refer to a spectral line (very narrow, specific wavelength emitted or absorbed) vs. a band, which indicates a wide range of wavelengths.

As I'm thinking about this, I'll also suggest for discussion "lane" or "track" as alternatives, though to me those both suggest motion along them.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution Nick. Could you edit your answer to provide a reference, dictionary definition or the like to support your suggestion for band as a common term for row and column. If rather you are suggesting a new usage, perhaps you could make that clear.

Comment: All excellent suggestions! They're all as generic and commonplace in regular english as *line* but less likely to be overloaded and thus ambiguous in the field of programming than some of the technical terms suggested. One thing is that none of them imply a 1-unit width but since they don't have prior set programming use, that can be easily and unambiguously specified in the code.

Answer (score 2):

A row does not have to be horizontal. In general usage a row can be anything arranged in a straight line, vertical or horizontal. It's only in the mathematical and computer usage that it implies horizontal.

To make it clear what you mean you could say

> vertical and horizontal rows

Comment: Agreed. In English *row* has both a more general and a more specific sense. It only necessarily takes on the more specific sense in contexts where it needs to contrast with *column*. In English this works but in programming it generally be too ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very late here, but I found this while googling for a related problem, and none of the suggestions quite fit my use-case (a sequence of cells on a game grid, but one in which the player moves around rather than connecting things like in OP's case, so "line" didn't make sense).

I ended up using "**path**", which is not a general-purpose solution for this kind of thing (because it can easily refer to nonlinear paths, or ones shorter than the width/height of the board), but in context it solved my problem nicely so I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the game after so many answers but how about ‘field’? This is a term used by database engineers to refer to a collection of data in a known configuration and has some crossover into math.