# Hypernym for queue, file, row, column, and stack

Tags: hypernyms

Words like row and rank imply that people/things are arranged horizontaly (beside each other), while words like queue and column imply a vertical positioning (behind each other). I need a word that can stand for either regardless whether the positioning is horizontal or vertical. Does it exist in English?

Comment: In a programming context, "slice" might work. Otherwise I don't think "row" is used exclusively for front to back arrangements. For example the rows of seats in a theater are side by side.

Comment: “Sequence” of numbers might be a possibility.

Comment: The proper course of action is to vote to reopen the duplicate [Generic term for 'row' and 'column'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132493/generic-term-for-row-and-column). '1-D array' is one possibility (if a single word is needed, the correct tag and an example sentence should be given). If a computer-specific term is desired, ELU is not the place to ask.

Comment: the post at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132493/generic-term-for-row-and-column suggests "**series**" - that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If, as the poster’s avatar suggests, the word is required in a computational context there is going to be a problem with ambiguity as many names for **ordered collections** of objects or variables are already taken (and are often ‘reserved’ words).

If this constraint does not exist, borrowing from the Java computing language, **List** seems a possibility for a collection of ordered objects (“first on the list”) without necessarily implying either a horizontal or vertical arrangement. (Although, to be fair, in everyday use it is often envisaged as vertical — “top of the list”.)

The problem is that one is using physical imagery to represent an abstract concept, and the words to describe physical arrangements have spatial associations. The only thing I can think of that is completely lacking either vertical or horizontal association is a holder for lottery tickets or numbered balls, as used to draw opponents in sporting knockout competitions. This is something of a cheat, however, as the numbers do not actually represent a **sequence**, which @Xanne suggested in a comment, but not as an answer. If one wishes a single word for a container for lottery tickets, one might revive the 18th century [**Punchboard**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punchboard).